# Good Logger library using c in Raspberry pi, for log the Lidar data for specific time interval and also need to delete the data after few hours

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

Initially, In my project, I'm using 2 lidars where I need to log the data every 15 minutes. for every minute I need to update the file name. and also I need to delete the logged data after two hours. is there any C library that will help me to solve my problem statement?

Comment: if you log data only every 15 minutes, why do you need to change the filename every minute ... sounds like an odd thing to do - there wouldn't be a library for such a specific thing anyway - just write some code, all that would be about a dozen lines

Comment: My aim is to get the log when the lidar misbehaving. So, for that i need to store the log data in a file. But for longer period we cant able to store it, memory shortage may be happening. So for that i will save the logs for 15 mins. and also for every 2 hours i will delete the previous created logs. So, that i can save memory and also i may have the logs for 2 hours from the lidar failed. which will be helping to sort out the errors.